# Is there any solution for scrapy_playwright to crawl and scrape the links?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I want to crawl list of links in a website and every single link need to be clicked to get a newpage, then scrape newpage. I've already written some code by scrapy-playwright, but it's just clicked then scraped only the 1st link, i know it's much better i scrape all the "href" first then request the links, but sometimes i get access to other pages, there is no "href" available in <><> to scrape, we need to click then the data come out, so is there any way to automate scrawl scrape the data in popup?

Here the web: https://boston.craigslist.org/search/npo

here my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
import scrapy_playwright

class PwspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'demoo'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://boston.craigslist.org/search/npo",
                             meta=dict(playwright=True,
                                       playwright_include_page=True,
                                       playwright_page_coroutines={
                                       
                                           PageCoroutine("click", selector="h3.result-heading"),
                                           PageCoroutine("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
                                           
                                        },
                             ),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            
            'body': response.css("section#postingbody::text").extract()
        }
```

Comment: Actually, every single link don't need to be clicked to get a newpage

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding, can you please show me how to get link without click?